# Reading value of bit in PxIN register

Tags: c, msp430, gpio

I need to get the value of an input but only need to get one specific bit. Im porting some software and can't seem to think of a way to get the value from PxIN for the microchip pic it looks like this:

```
unsigned char idx;
for (idx = 0; idx < 8; idx++) {
    unsigned char byte |= RC1;
}
```

How would I go about reading the input pin with a MSP430? I am using Code Composer Studio v5.3.

Comment: Which compiler? It makes a difference!

Comment: @LeonHeller Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to read PxIN and then use a bitwise AND that puts the result in another variable.

e.g. `result = PxIN & (1<<n)` to read the n-th bit.

Besides, (at least with CCS and I think - but I have no way to test - with GCC, it might change with other compilers) instead of doing bit shifts, the `msp430.h` header defines a `BITn` constant which you can use here.

Comment: It depends on the compiler!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to shift bits around to line up where you need them, it's often easier and simpler to write something like:

```
if (port & bitmask) byte |= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the CrossWorks compiler you can use:

```
a = P1IN & BIT0;
```

to read BIT0 of port P1.